# Save dollar symbol as string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, symbols

How can I save dollar symbol as `String`, it gives me error when doing so.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> currencies = {
  "dollar": "\$",
  // other currencies
};
```